# Смена CMS с сохранением каталога товаров

Tags: cms

Можно ли поменять одну CMS на другую, сохранив каталог товаров?

Comment: Можно. О каких CMS идёт речь?

Comment: я бы сказал, что вопрос слишком общий для данного сайта.

Comment: Используй экспорт, импорт товаров или переноси вручную.

Answer (score 2):

Да, это действительно возможно, но требует выгрузки из базы данных всех данных каталога и роутов. Затем нужно написать или воспользоваться скриптом миграции. Так же можно вручную добавить в базу данных, перестроив мигрировавшую таблицу базы данных текущей CMS на мигрируемую. В ручную самый простой вариант, но требует времени.

Comment: И сколько в среднем стоит программа для переноса базы данных каталога?

Comment: Вот пример http://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/yenisite.migrator/ для миграции из битры в другие системы. Можно свой заказать у кодера, но может выйти дороже

Comment: Все зависит от того, что у вас под капотом